# DynamoDB filter items not contains

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have the following problem:

Partition key (pk) and Sort key (sk):

```
pk   sk
1    ITEMS#1
1    ORDERS#1

2    ITEMS#1
3    ITEMS#2
```

How can I retrieve all pk's that does not contain orders? I have tried the filter:

```
sk not contains "ORDERS"
```

But that returns

```
pk   sk
1    ITEMS#1
2    ITEMS#1
3    ITEMS#2
```

Where I only want to return pk 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this efficiently, you'll have to pre-materialize the orders-or-not fact into your data and structure things in such a way that the fact is appropriately indexed and ready to use.

For example, you can create an item under each PK with an SK of `META` for metadata about that PK, and on that item you can have an attribute of `HasOrders` that's present if it has any orders in that item collection. Then you can create a GSI using that as the GSI partition key and very efficiently find all items that have orders with a Query.

You'll have to update the META every time someone places their first order.